# Swift 3 - Async Request table empty, after refresh filled

Tags: swift, uitableview, asynchronous, request, alamofire

I'm new to Swift and currently building an app, which is showing me on the first page a tableview with an image and a textfield.
I have two request, one to fetch all images and one to fetch all names.
My problem is, when I call both request, the table is "empty" - when i pull down and refresh the table, then the data appears. The weird thing is, when i do only one request and "disable" the other one. It works fluently. (Tested this for both individual requests).

First Request:

```
func getAllToDo(){
        let url:String = "XXXXXXXXXXX"
        let getAllToDosRequest = Alamofire.request(url)
        getAllToDosRequest.responseJSON{ response in
            switch response.result{
            case .success(let JSON):
                let response = JSON as! NSArray
                self.listOfTodos.removeAll()
                for item in response {
                    let obj = item as! NSDictionary
                    let toDo = ToDo(id: obj["id_ToDo"] as! Int, name: obj["name"] as! String, todo_description: obj["description"] as! String)
                    self.listOfTodos.append(toDo)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Second Request:

```
func getAllImages(){
        let url:String = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        let getAllImagesRequest = Alamofire.request(url)
        getAllImagesRequest.responseJSON{ response in
            switch response.result{
            case .success(let JSON):
                let response = JSON as! NSArray
                self.listOfImages.removeAll()
                for item in response {
                    let obj = item as! NSDictionary
                    let image = Image(id: obj["id"] as! Int, binary: obj["binary"] as! String, name: obj["name"] as! String)
                    self.listOfImages.append(image)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Thread Handling:

```
func refreshData(){
        let myGroup = DispatchGroup()
        for i in 0 ..< 2 {
            myGroup.enter()
            if(i == 0){
                getAllImages()
                print("Finished request \(i)")
                myGroup.leave()
            }
            if(i == 1){
                getAllToDo()
                print("Finished request \(i)")
                myGroup.leave()
            }
        }
        myGroup.notify(queue: .main){
            print("All finished")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
            }
        }
    }
```

TableView:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        refreshData()
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *){
            tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
        } else{
            tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
        }
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return listOfTodos.count
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell
        let todo = listOfTodos[indexPath.row]
        let image = listOfImages[indexPath.row]
        cell.myLabel.text = todo.name
        cell.myImage.image = convert64BaseToImage(binary: image.binary)
        return(cell)
    }
```

If I am doing it as it is shown in the code, the tableView is empty after start, but when i pull down it has the data. What Am i doing wrong? If I do only one seperate request, the tableView gets filled... It seems like that the tableView is called before the data is completely loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a serious *design bug* in your `refreshData()` function.

The functions `getAllToDo()` and `getAllImages()` are both *asynchronous*. In other words, they keep on processing even after the function returns. Your current `refreshData` wrongly assumes that such processing ends when each function returns — this is not the case! As a result, you are leaving the `DispatchGroup` too soon. Finally, this perfectly explains your empirical observation:

> It seems like that the tableView is called *before* the data is completely loaded.

A standard pattern, for handling asynchronous communication, is to pass a *completion handler* to the asynchronous function when calling it. For instance:

```
func getAllToDo(completion: () -> Void) {
    ...
    getAllToDosRequest.responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result { 
            ...
        }
        completion() // Processing is done!
    }
 }
```

and then, in your `refreshData()` function, define an appropriate completion handler:

```
getAllToDo {
    print("Finished request \(i)")
    myGroup.leave()
}
```

Of course, you must do the same refactoring on your `getAllImages()` function as well.

---

By the way, you could simplify this:

```
myGroup.notify(queue: .main){
    print("All finished")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
}
```

as:

```
myGroup.notify(queue: .main){
    print("All finished")
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

You are postponing work on the *same* queue you are in — no performance gain will come out of this. In fact, the *opposite* may happen, given: queue processing overhead; locking costs; context switching; etc.